# Show hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <div href="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">1</div>
 <div href="#collapse2" class="nav-toggle">2</div>
 <div href="#collapse3" class="nav-toggle">3</div>
 <div href="#collapse4" class="nav-toggle">4</div>
 <div href="#collapse5" class="nav-toggle">5</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none');
        });
      });

});
```

[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] when click on a div I want to show a data box below the row. A separate data box for each div but show at the end of the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got only two such divs, it's really simple. Start off with one hidden and when the visible one is clicked toggle both.

```js
$('.nav-toggle').last().hide().end().on('click', function() {
     $('.nav-toggle').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div href="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">1</div>
 <div href="#collapse2" class="nav-toggle">2</div>
```

If there're more than two such `div`s the technique has to change slightly:

```js
    $('.nav-toggle').not(':first').hide().end().on('click', function() {
          var navs = $('.nav-toggle');
          var index = navs.index(this);
          var next  = (index + 1) % navs.length;
          navs.eq(next).add( this ).toggle();
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="nav-toggle">1</div>
    <div class="nav-toggle">2</div>
    <div class="nav-toggle">3</div>
    <div class="nav-toggle">4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, suppose I have 7 boxes  in a row like in a calendar and when user click on a box, a data box appears just under the row?

Comment: Can you post a separate question for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wayBwp

```
$(".p").click(function(){
  $(".c").removeAttr( "hidden" );
  $(".p").attr("hidden","hidden");
})

$(".c").click(function(){
  $(".p").removeAttr( "hidden" );
  $(".c").attr("hidden","hidden");
})
```